# show/hide div based on select option with getelementsbyclassname

Tags: javascript, select, getelementsbyclassname

Im trying to get the divs to switch style properties when selected form select menu. Any help would be great!

there is the code:

the select tag(where i have the value to the script function):

```
 <div style="float: right; margin-right: 5%; width: auto;">
        <select style="border: 3px intset; border-radius: 5px; border-color: #17FFFF;" onchange="showstuff(this.value);">
            <optgroup label="Lisboa">
                <option value="Picoas">Picoas</option>
                <option value="Benfica">Benfica</option>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label="Porto">
                <option value="Felgueiras">Felgueiras</option>
                <option value="Maia">Maia</option>
            </optgroup>
        </select>
    </div>
```

the div's with the class name:

```
<div style="width: 90%; height: 50%; background-color: #09C; overflow: scroll; overflow-x: hidden; margin-bottom: 15%; margin-left: 5%; margin-right: 5%; text-align: left; color: #000; font-size: 60%;">
    <div class="Picoas" style="height: 30%; width: 100%; background-color: #CCEAFF; display:none;">
        Timberland Picoas<br />
        Centro Colombo Morada: Av. Lusíada, Centro Colombo Piso 1, Loja 1.095<br />
        1500-392 Lisboa
    </div>
    <div class="Felgueiras" style="height: 30%; width: 100%; background-color: #CCEAFF;
        margin-top: 2%;display:none;">
        Timberland Felgueiras<br />
        Centro Colombo Morada: Av. Lusíada, Centro Colombo Piso 1, Loja 1.095<br />
        1500-392 Lisboa
    </div>
    <div class="Picoas" style="height: 30%; width: 100%; background-color: #CCEAFF; margin-top: 2%;display:none;">
        Timberland Picoas<br />
        Centro Colombo Morada: Av. Lusíada, Centro Colombo Piso 1, Loja 1.095<br />
        1500-392 Lisboa
    </div>
    <div class="Felgueiras" style="height: 30%; width: 100%; background-color: #CCEAFF;
        margin-top: 2%;display:none;">
        Timberland Felgueiras<br />
        Centro Colombo Morada: Av. Lusíada, Centro Colombo Piso 1, Loja 1.095<br />
        1500-392 Lisboa
    </div>
    <div class="Benfica" style="height: 30%; width: 100%; background-color: #CCEAFF; margin-top: 2%;display:none;">
        Timberland Benfica<br />
        Centro Colombo Morada: Av. Lusíada, Centro Colombo Piso 1, Loja 1.095<br />
        1500-392 Lisboa
    </div>
    <div class="Maia" style="height: 30%; width: 100%; background-color: #CCEAFF; margin-top: 2%;display:none;">
        Timberland Maia<br />
        Centro Colombo Morada: Av. Lusíada, Centro Colombo Piso 1, Loja 1.095<br />
        1500-392 Lisboa
    </div>
    <div class="Benfica" style="height: 30%; width: 100%; background-color: #CCEAFF; margin-top: 2%;display:none;">
        Timberland Benfica<br />
        Centro Colombo Morada: Av. Lusíada, Centro Colombo Piso 1, Loja 1.095<br />
        1500-392 Lisboa
    </div>
    <div class="Maia" style="height: 30%; width: 100%; background-color: #CCEAFF; margin-top: 2%;display:none;">
        Timberland Picoas<br />
        Centro Colombo Morada: Av. Lusíada, Centro Colombo Piso 1, Loja 1.095<br />
        1500-392 Lisboa
    </div>
</div>
```

the script and the class definitions:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function showstuff(element) {
        var elementsPicoas = document.getElementsByClassName("Picoas");
        elementsPicoas.style.display = element == "Picoas" ? "block" : "none";
         var elementsBenfica = document.getElementsByClassName("Benfica");
        elementsBenfica.style.display = element == "Benfica" ? "block" : "none";
         var elementsFelgueiras = document.getElementsByClassName("Felgueiras");
        elementsFelgueiras.style.display = element == "Felgueiras" ? "block" : "none";
         var elementsMaia = document.getElementsByClassName("Maia");
        elementsMaia.style.display = element == "Maia" ? "block" : "none";
    } 
</script>
     <style>
  .Picoas{}
  .Felgueiras{}
  .Benfica{}
  .Maia{} 
  </style>
```

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: I think its this?? **Im trying to get the divs to switch style properties when selected form select menu**

Comment: If you need richer interaction on your page, you should seriously consider using [jQuery](http://jquery.com) or [zepto](http://zeptojs.com). Also, try to extract your inline styles into a style block or a stylesheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to do it without jQuery!

```
function showstuff(selectedElementClass) {

    var elementClasses = [
        "Picoas",
        "Benfica",
        "Felgueiras",
        "Maia"
    ];

    for (var i = 0; i < elementClasses.length; i++) {
        var elements = document.getElementsByClassName(elementClasses[i]);

        for (var j = 0; j < elements.length; j++) {
            var element = elements[j];
            element.style.display = (element.className === selectedElementClass)? "block" : "none";
        }
    }
}
```

You can see it in action here: https://tinker.io/38459/3

Comment: You can't do *anything* without jQuery, Nick. Everyone knows that.

Comment: @Yatrix Depends on the project! Maybe this is the only interactive part he needs. If so, why pull in a huge library like jQuery when a bit of plain javascript works just as well?

Comment: I thought my sarcasm was obvious...guess not. =)

Comment: @NickPorter you can do anything without jquery but it's about the quantity, as jquerys slogan 'write less, do more' says, also its a lot easier to do it with jquery most of the time :-D

Comment: @user891362 True that, but sometimes using the DOM api is better than  including a >30kb dependency. Depends on what you're building.

Comment: @NickPorter that is true, but everything ive built with javascript i always include jquery as most of my projects are big :-D

Comment: hello, this is the first time im working with javascript and jquery .. I started to use the jquery libraries but then moved and did all the code with html + javascript + css.. because when i create buttons with jquery is super hard change the styles because jquery javascript changed constantly the .css . . . or im a noob and don't know how to do it the right way loool

Many thanks to all, especially to NickPorter.
It is people like you guys who make great sites like this;)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using jQuery which enables you to do stuff like

```
$(".Picoas, .Benfica, .Felgueiras, .Maia").hide(); //hide them all
$("." + element).show(); //display only the selected one
```

**Update**

Sorry, this was too fast. The real problem is, that the getElementsByClassName function returns more than one element, because you have all the classes you are checking for 2 times in your code.

What you can do is - if you don't want to use jQuery - something like this:

```
function display(className, mode)
{
    var elms = document.getElementsByClassName(className);

    for (var i = 0; i < elms.length; i++)
    {
        elms[i].style.display = mode;
    }

}

function showstuff(element) 
{
    //hide 'em all
    var allElements = ["Picoas", "Benfica", "Felgueiras", "Maia"];

    for (var i = 0; i < allElements.length; i++)
    {
        display(allElements[i], "none");
    }

    //show the one selected
    display(element, "block");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

More efficient way to do this with jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#changeme").change(function(){
     $(".dynamic").css("display", "none");
     $("."+this.value).css("display", "block");
   });
});
</script>

<style>
.dynamic
   {
       height: 30%; 
       width: 100%; 
       background-color: #CCEAFF; 
       margin-top: 2%;
       display:none;
   }
.Picoas{}
.Felgueiras{}
.Benfica{}
.Maia{} 
</style>

<div class="Picoas dynamic">
    Timberland Picoas<br />
    Centro Colombo Morada: Av. Lusíada, Centro Colombo Piso 1, Loja 1.095<br />
    1500-392 Lisboa
</div>
<div class="Felgueiras dynamic">
    Timberland Felgueiras<br />
    Centro Colombo Morada: Av. Lusíada, Centro Colombo Piso 1, Loja 1.095<br />
    1500-392 Lisboa
</div>
(etc.)
```

http://jsbin.com/welcome/47377/edit